# What Joomla extension to use for a list of animals, each animal links to own page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a list of animals. Each animal got his own info page (or shared page with other animals). I want to put the animals in a search engine. So when people search for a animal they will be redirected to the right info page. Ajax search is a must. 
i think there are 2 options to get it working. 
1.) Add animals to a search engine and add also the info page (url)
2.) Add animals to a search engine and add the animals on the info pages by invisible/meta tags so the earch engine will find the right pages.

I have searched for a extension but cannot find the right one. Someone knows a (free) extension what will do the trick?

I now have a large list of animals so people can click and get redirected but that looks cheap ;-)

Comment: Have you tried **Rok Ajax Search**?

Comment: i am testing it right now. Looks great, now i need to find out how to exclude all the content that is on my website right now. "Hide Divs: This option allows you to set which elements of your site you wish to be excluded from searching. Enter the ID names separated by a comma such as: logo-module, side-column, and maincontent." I need to exclude articles or article categories :-/   btw... Lodder is your name? Funny, that is my last name ;-)

Comment: I don't think excluding is possible with this module. If it's not what you need, I'm sure there might be something more suitable on the Joomla Extensions Directory. Lodder is also my second name, but most people call me that, so it's my username on websites ;)

Comment: Thanks for the support, i now know how to move on with my project ;-)